# Jenkins y MsBuild con una web MVC

Tags: c#, mvc, asp, jenkins

Buenas, me gustaría que me ayudarais con la herramienta de integración continua Jenkins, pero sobre todo el problema que tengo es con el msbuild.
 Tengo una web en asp con paquetes nuget que en el VS compila y publica perfectamente sin embargo con el MSbuild y Jenkins me compila bien pero al publicar me guarda archivos no necesarios alguna sugerencia Gracias!

Paquetes Nuget:

```
C:\nuget\nuget.exe restore .\GnossWeb\
```

Compilación

```
/t:build /tv:14.0 /m
```

Publicación:

```
/t:rebuild /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0 /p:configuration=Debug  /p:Targets=Publish /p:DeployOnBuild=true
```

También lo intente con esto :

```
/p:Configuration=Release
/p:DeployOnBuild=True
/p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish
/p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem
/p:DeleteExistingFiles=True
```

Todo lo anterior con el msbuild

Comment: Como estas, ¿podrías aclarar un poco más a que te refieres con "guardar archivos no necesarios"?

Comment: Buenas muchas gracias por contestar, por ejemplo se queda el archivo .csproj, y ahora mismo no te se decir cuales mas pero eran unos cuantos que si comparamos con la publicación del VS no aparecen. Gracias Un Saludo!

Comment: Mira para realizar para realizar la compilación y generación de dlls se realiza a partir de los archivos del proyecto tales como el .csproj que mencionas, pero la publicación de los mismos deberían ser los que están dentro de la carpeta Bin del proyecto, también podes cambiar esta ruta desde el archivo .pubxml que se encuentra dentro de la carpeta properties del proyecto, así lo realizo yo para que me genere los binarios en otra ubicación que no es la misma donde esta el proyecto.

Answer (score 0):

Se puede publicar desde MSBUILD haciendo:

```
msbuild MiAplicacion.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=MiPerfil
```

Donde MiPerfil es es nombre al perfil de publicacion. 
Podes encontrarlo en tu poyecto dentro de la carpeta Porperties/PublishProfiles. Alli debe existir un archivo de tipo xml llamado MiPerfil.pubxml.

Lo mas importante es el tag *publishUrl*; es el path de publicación.

```
 <publishUrl>..\Paginas\MiPagina</publishUrl>
```

Lo podes hacer apuntar a un path relativo y de ahí tomar la carpeta para hacer despliegues en Jenkins por ejemplo